# What is the VB.Net Code Equivelant for c# Anonymous Type code?

Tags: c#, vb.net, language-features

Can someone tell me what the code equivelant in VB.Net to this C# code is?

```
new {name="value"}
```

Comment: I know the title is bad, i will update when the second part of the question is answered.

Comment: updated title, thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called Anonymous Types and the VB equivalent is :

```
 New With {.Name = "value"}
```

Comment: To be 100% equivalent with C# anonymous types key should add the "Key" keyword before .Name.

Answer (score 0):

That feature is called an anonymous type.

Comment: No, it's an object initializer if you specify the type as well. This is an anonymous type.