# How do I convert this from C# to VB.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

ASP.NET MVC - what is this in VB.NET?

```
Html.TextBox( "name", null, new { @class = "css-class" } );
```

Comment: As asked, this is an entirely plzsendtehcodez question.  You should edit this to ask a question about what that actually means and what the equivalent construct is in VB.NET, not just ask for the conversion.

Comment: @Cody, I second that -- down vote for the bad question title (I thought it was "how do I convert from C# to VB.net" in the general case, not "how do you do this...").

Comment: Umm... then what should the question have read?  I wasn't sure how to ask the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost exact duplicate:
[What is the VB.Net Code Equivelant for c# Anonymous Type code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407586/what-is-the-vb-net-code-equivelant-for-c-anonymous-type-code)

> This is called Anonymous Types and the
>   VB equivalent is :
>
> New With {.Name = "value"}

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the "." in my code - I couldn't for the life of me remember that.